# tornadoweb Access-Control-Allow-Origin jquery POST

Tags: jquery, post, tornado, cors

I want to enable CORS request via jQuery using POST request to my handler. Below tornado request and jquery

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1000)
        #self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
        self.set_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
```

but after calling:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: _url,      
            /*      
            beforeSend : function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType)
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
            },*/
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'POST');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },  
            data : _data,            
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success:  function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log("ajax response: "+resp+" json="+JSON.stringify(resp));
            }
        });
```

and I am sending:
[image]

I receive: Reload the page to get source for "my post url goes here".
Any ideas where is catch?

Comment: What is the problem?  What is your question?

Comment: The problem is the response: I do not send 'Reload the page...' but simple:
self.set_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
self.write( tornado.escape.json_encode({'no': 1}  ))
self.finish()

Comment: which class is handling your `POST` requests? can you post your code?